# Create list of lists with multiprocessing.Manager().list()

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

What is the correct / more pythonic way of creating a list of empty lists in python using multiprocessing ? I mean this object must be accessible and will be modified (append to) by a pool of workers.

What I have at the moment is this:

```
import multiprocessing

len_outer_list = 10
manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
outer_list = manager.list()
for _ in range(len_outer_list):
    outer_list.append(manager.list()) # add the empty inner lists
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you answered yourself within 1 minute of posting the question?

Comment: Thought it might be useful for others since I did not think at first that the numpy like syntax would work, just tried it. But yeah I hesitated because of the timing T_T Still useful for others, wouldn't have posted it tomorrow ...

Comment: @rdas There is nothing wrong with answering one's own questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this works fine:

```
outer_list = manager.list([manager.list() for _ in range(len_outer_list)])
```